# Erlang unique_integer returns the same integer after restart

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I need to number my records so that I can always compare what came "later" from what came "before".

For this I used the `unique_integer` function:

```
Tag = erlang:unique_integer([monotonic]),
```

and then I would compare any two events:

```
Event1.tag < Event2.tag
```

would mean that Event1 came before Event2.

However, when I *restart* the erlang node, it starts numbering *from* the beginning again:

```
event1  -5555
event2  -5554
event3  -5553

-- restart the system

event4  -5555
event5  -5554
event6  -5553
```

Now my sorting is not working as intended.

Is there any way to generate long sequential number that picks up where it left off after restarts?

P.S.: If it is useful, I am using mnesia to store my events, and so I need an increasing row number for record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the feature I was looking for: `mnesia:dirty_update_counter`.

Thanks to this [excellent post](http://dudefrommangalore.blogspot.ca/2009/03/auto-increment-in-mnesia-database.html) on the matter:

> ```
> mnesia:dirty_update_counter(unique_ids, record_type, 1), 
> io:format("Id => ~p~n", [Id]), 
>
> Id1 = mnesia:dirty_update_counter(unique_ids,record_type, 1), 
> io:format( "Id => ~p~n", [Id1]), 
>
> Id2 = mnesia:dirty_update_counter(unique_ids, another_type, 1), 
> io:format("Id => ~p~n", [Id2]),
> ```
>
> The output you will get is
>
> ```
> Id => 1 
> Id => 2 
> Id => 1
> ```
>
> A single table can be used to generate the unique ids for other
>   tables. In this example, unique ids are generated for record_type and
>   another_type. Posted by Dude From Mangalore at 3:19 PM

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#unique_integer-0):

> **erlang:unique_integer() -> integer()**
>
> Generates and returns an integer unique on current runtime system instance. The same as calling erlang:unique_integer([]).

So what you're seeing is consistent with the defined behavior.

---

I'm not clear what you need this for, and the correct solution depends on your exact needs. Assuming you have events coming in rapidly and you're planning to use `ordered_set` to store them in Mnesia by arrival time I can think of a few approaches:

- Have a single process in charge of inserts. It can initialize with the max ID from the table and increment on each insert.
- Generate a key with `erlang:system_time(nano_seconds)` that's unique-ish
- Generate a key with `{erlang:system_time(nano_seconds), make_ref()}` to ensure uniqueness even when the timestamps are the same

Comment: I use `set`, not ordered set. Regarding single process, I already have one in charge of all the inserts so that's not an issue. The obvious solution for me is to have my own counter and read the last value stored when I start up the process. I was curious if there was another way. Regarding your last suggestion, (make_ref()) - I'm afraid that won't be useful to me since I want to have *all* the events in absolute order. Will `erlang:system_time` doc states that it is `This time is not a monotonically increasing time.`. FYI - I am implementing an eventstore.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov As far as I can tell, that only ensure that time does not fast-forward. In my case I only care about absolute ordering of entities, not the absence of "gaps" in the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Use `{erlang:system_time(seconds), erlang:unique_integer([monotonic])}` when you expect you don't restart within lest than one second. Otherwise `{erlang:system_time(), erlang:unique_integer([monotonic])}` is safe bet.

You can store the value of erlang:system_time(seconds) when your system or process starts and save call `erlang:system_time/0,1`.

Comment: What if I transfer my erlang node to another system that has incorrect time settings? Would it not generate identical system_time entries to what I already have?

Comment: @drozzy: Yes it would as any other solution except using UUID or central _authority_ timestamp provider. You didn't mention distributed system scenario.